# Populate Google Apps flexTable with filtered Spreadsheet Data and returning changes to spreadsheet

Tags: database, google-apps-script, handler, flextable

I am writing an application that pulls task data (for a task management system) from rows in a Google Spreadsheet with conditions matching a query.  I then send this data into a flexTable next to a checkbox with an onClickHandler as well as a textbox to enter in hours data.  Below is the simplest example of how I have achieved this:

```
\\establish handler for checkboxes that are generated in flexTable
var updateHandler = app.createServerClickHandler('updateTasksfunc');
updateHandler.addCallbackElement(taskTable);

\\search Google Spreadsheet for rows matching condition
for(var i=1; i< taskData.length; i++){
   if (taskData [i][1] !=employee){
     continue;      
   }

\\look up if task is already completed, and set checkbox value to true/false
var complete = taskData[i][8].toString();
if(complete==="true"){var checkbox=true;}else{var checkbox=false;}

\\populate flexTable with values from spreadsheet query
taskTable.setWidget(i,0,app.createTextBox().setName('hours'+i).setWidth('50').setId("hour"+i)).setWidget(i,1,app.createCheckBox().setValue(checkbox).setName('complete'+i).addClickHandler(updateHandler)).setWidget(i,2,app.createLabel(taskData[i][2]).setWidth('250')).setWidget(i,3,app.createLabel(taskData[i][3]).setWidth('250')).setWidget(i,4,app.createLabel(taskData[i][4])).setWidget(i,5,app.createLabel(taskData[i][5])).setWidget(i,6,app.createLabel(taskData[i][6])).setWidget(i,7,app.createLabel(taskData[i][7])).setWidget(i,8,app.createTextBox().setVisible(false).setName("dataRow"+i).setValue(i))
}
```

\edits to doGet()

```
var numberOfItems = app.createTextBox().setName('rows').setValue(i).setVisible(false);
var rows1 = i+1;
taskTable.setWidget(rows1,0,numberOfItems)
```

I have stored the spreadsheet data row in the invisible textbox in column 8 of the flex table that I intend to use in the clickHandler function to update the Google Spreadsheet.

I have successfully activated a click handler that runs when a checkbox is clicked; however, I have not yet successfully figured out a way to grab data from the flexTable that I can use to update the Spreadsheet.

//Functional code below

```
function updateTasksfunc(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

  var taskSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SPREADSHEETID');
  var taskSH = taskSS.getSheets()[0];
  var taskData = taskSS.getDataRange().getValues();

  var results = [];// an array to collect results
  var numberOfItems = e.parameter.rows; 
  app.add(app.createLabel(numberOfItems));
  for(var n=0;n<numberOfItems;n++){
    results.push([e.parameter['check'+n]]);// each element is an array of 2 values
  }
  for(var i=1;i<results.length;i++){
    var check = results[i][0];
    var row = i+1;
    taskSH.getRange(row,9,1,1).setValue(check);
  }
return app;  
}
```

I am getting a generic error: cannot find function getRowCount() from generic.

I assume that this means that I am not properly calling my flexTable.

Any thoughts??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

flextables are not working like spreadsheets, you can't get widgets values directly as part of the table. You have to get every textBox and checkBox separately using `e.parameter.Name`.

You can do that easily in a loop but you'll have to know the number of textBoxes to be able to rebuild the names just as you did to create them in the `doGet` function.

I would suggest to store this number in a tag  on one of your widget or in a separate hidden widget ([hidden class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/hidden) or [invisible textBox](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/text-box#setVisible%28Boolean%29)). Then you will be able to get the values like this :

```
...
var results = [];// an array to collect results
var numberOfItems = Number(e.parameter.itemNumbers); // this is the var you are missing right now and need to add. This is the solution of a separate hidden widget
for(var n=0;n<numberOfItems;n++){
  results.push([e.parameter['hours'+n],e.parameter['complete'+n]]);// each element is an array of 2 values
  }
... // from here you will have an 2D array with all your values and you can continue like you did=.
```

Comment: Thank You!  You are a life saver!  I have the program working at a basal level now.